# create a android contactList view?

Tags: android

Hi i am trying to create a basic contact list that has same functionality has the native one i.e. arranged in alphabetical order and have the scrolling thumb tab on the side to scroll through letters.

How do i create that scroll tab thing? i will use some sort of sorting algorithm to sort my contact list in order so that should be fine but im wondering how to do the fast thumb tab scroll seen in the pic below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After several hours trying to solve this I finally found the incredibly simple answer. Simply enable fastscroll in the layout for the list.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    />
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:fastScrollEnabled